# HTML form - check if email entered correctly?

Tags: forms, email

I creating Contact us form and i want in email section that if email entered wrong way (not name@example.com), user wouldn't be able to submit form.

input:

> `<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/>`

Comment: type="email" but i don't think it work in IE 9 and below.

Comment: eMail validation is fraught with difficulties. The only way to be sure an email address is valid is to send an email to it and track a response.

Comment: @zeeba `email` is an HTML5 type, and it's not supported very well even in current browsers.

Comment: ah, roger that. thanks Mike

Comment: Just Google "email validation form", there are a LOT of articles on this.

Answer (score 0):

With regexp using javascript/php (or whatever) you would be able to validate an email format : presence of "@", presence of ".dom", but you will have to hard code to avoid something like "example.com".

I would suggest to use a validation/activation mechanism : send an email with a link, when user click the link you receive a notification, that means that email is valid so you can take care of it !

You can check this topic : [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)
But it does not take care about something like "name@example.com".
As Mike W said in comments, the only way to validate a valid email is to send an email.

Also, you could have fun trying to trap auto-response for invalid email by checking the sender mailbox ;)